# Lapply to a list of dataframes only if column exists

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, lapply

I have a list of dataframes for which I want to obtain (in a separate dataframe) the row mean of a specified column which may or may not exist in all dataframes of the list. My problem comes when the specified column does not exist in at least one of the dataframes of the list.

Assume the following example list of dataframes:

```
df1 <- read.table(text = 'X   A   B   C
                       name1  1   2   3
                       name2  5  10   4',
                 header = TRUE)  

df2 <- read.table(text = 'X   B   C   A
                       name1  8   1  31
                       name2  9   9   8', 
                 header = TRUE)

df3 <- read.table(text = 'X   B   A   E
                       name1  9   9  29
                       name2  5  15  55', 
                 header = TRUE)

mylist_old <-list(df1, df2)
mylist_new <-list(df1, df2, df3)
```

Assume I want to `rowMeans` column `C` the following piece of code works perfectly when the list of dataframe (`mylist_old`) is composed of elements `df1` and `df2`, :

```
Mean_C <- rowMeans(do.call(cbind, lapply(mylist_old, "[", "C")))
Mean_C <- as.data.frame(Mean_C)
```

The trouble comes when the list is composed of at least one dataframe for which column `C` does not exist, which in my example is the case of `df3`, that is for list `mylist_new`:

```
Mean_C <- rowMeans(do.call(cbind, lapply(mylist_new, "[", "C")))
```

Leads to: "Error in `[.data.frame`(X[[i]], ...) : undefined columns selected

One way to circumvent this issue is to exclude `df3` from `mylist_new`. However, my real program has a list of 64 dataframes for which I do not know whether column `C` exists or not. I would have like to `lapply` my piece of code only if column `C` is detected as existing, that is applying the command to the list of dataframes but only for dataframes for which existence of column `C` is true.

I tried this

```
if("C" %in% colnames(mylist_new))
 {
     Mean_C <- rowMeans(do.call(cbind, lapply(mylist_new, "[", "C")))
     Mean_C <- as.data.frame(Mean_C)    
 }
```

But nothing happens, probably because `colnames` refers to the list and not to each dataframe of the list. With 64 dataframes, I cannot refer to each "manually" and need an automated procedure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one option to `Filter` the `list` elements and then apply the `lapply` on the filtered `list`

```
rowMeans(do.call(cbind, lapply(Filter(function(x) "C" %in% names(x), 
               mylist_new), `[[`, "C")))
#[1] 2.0 6.5
```

---

or using `tidyverse` without `Filter`ing, but making use of `select` to ignore the cases where the column is not present

```
library(tidyverse)
map(mylist_new, ~ .x %>% 
                   select(one_of("C"))) %>% # gives a warning
                   bind_cols  %>%
                   rowMeans
#[1] 2.0 6.5
```

It may be better to have some warning that the column is not present

---

Or without a warning

```
map(mylist_new, ~ .x %>% 
                 select(matches("^C$"))) %>%
                 bind_cols  %>%
                 rowMeans
#[1] 2.0 6.5
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use *if* to check names before we do the subset

```
rowMeans(do.call(cbind,
         lapply(mylist_new, function(x) if('C' %in% names(x)) x['C'] else NA)),na.rm = TRUE)
```

Or using map_if in *purrr 0.3.2*

```
library(purrr)
rowMeans(do.call(cbind,map_if(mylist_new, 
                              function(x) 'C' %in% names(x), 
                              'C', .else=~return(NA))),na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 2.0 6.5
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `purrr::safely`, it will return for each iteration a list with a `result` and `error` element, then we can transpose, extract `result` and remove the `NULL` result with `compact` :

```
library(tidyverse)
rowMeans(do.call(cbind, transpose(
  lapply(mylist_new, safely(`[`), "C"))$result %>% compact()))
# [1] 2.0 6.5
```

We could also use the `otherwise` parameter to have a `NA` result rather than `NULL`, and we can set `na.rm` to `TRUE` in `rowMeans`.

```
rowMeans(na.rm = TRUE, do.call(cbind, transpose(
  lapply(mylist_new, safely(`[`, otherwise= NA), "C"))$result))
# [1] 2.0 6.5
```

---

This was to address your case with minimal modifications. If I have to solve this precise issue I would do it the following way :

```
map(mylist_new,  "C") %>% compact() %>% pmap_dbl(~mean(c(...)))
# [1] 2.0 6.5
```

We extract the `C` element, remove it when it's `NULL`, and then compute mean by element.

This might be more efficient (not sure):

```
map(set_names(mylist_new),  "C") %>% compact() %>% as_tibble() %>% rowMeans()
# [1] 2.0 6.5
```

---

One more, using reshaping this time :

```
map_dfr(mylist_new, ~gather(.,,,-1)) %>% 
  group_by(X) %>%
  filter(key == "C") %>%
  summarize_at("value", mean)

# # A tibble: 2 x 2
# X     value
# <fct> <dbl>
# 1 name1   2  
# 2 name2   6.5
```

---

And a base version, quite readable, with a somewhat awkward step where several columns have the same name, but it's on a temp object so that's not that bad:

```
wide <- do.call(cbind, mylist_new)
rowMeans(wide[names(wide) == "C"])
# [1] 2.0 6.5
```